# Print (unsorted) dictonary in template django

Tags: html, django, templates, dictionary, django-templates

I have a list of dict:

```
Dict = [ {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
        {'key1':'value4', 'key2':'value5','key3':'value6'},
        {'key1':'value7', 'key2':'value8','key3':'value9'}]
```

I need to display it in this order:

```
KEY1     KEY2   KEY3
value1  value2  value3
value4  value5  value6
value7  value8  value9
```

The keys have to be printed only one time, following this order.

Now I have this code in template, but the values don't match with the column of the keys:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        {% for k in listkey %}
            <td>{{ k }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
        {% for raw in dict %}
        <tr>
            {% for k,v in raw.items %}
                <td>{{ v }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

In views.py:

```
listkeys = ['key1','key2','key3']
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already noticed, dict in python is unsorted, so unless you specify explicitly in template which value to visit, there's no way to loop dict in any order.

You could change your data structure instead, to build a list of lists:

```
another_datastructure = []

for item in Dict:
    # temp would hold value of key1, key2, key3 on current dict entry
    temp = []
    for key in listkeys:
        temp.append(Dict[key])
    another_datastructure.append(temp)
```

Now you have a list of lists that each list has key following key1, key2 key3 order. Then you could just loop on it and guarantee the order.

Comment: Thanks, but i avoid this solution because i may need to get one specific value. But with your suggestion i think that i'll build two datastructure: one just for display data in template (list of list), and another for the calculations with the value(list of dict).

Comment: Oh you mean you want to get specific value of a dict in template? That can be done doing {{ dict.key1 }}. Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups.

Answer (score 1):

From your `Dict` list you can create dictionary with `key` values as your keys, and `value` will be the `list` of all combined values of previous list.

```
# use lowercase variable names and dont pick name like "list", "dict", "tuple" etc.

from collections import defaultdict

your_list = [{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
             {'key1':'value4', 'key2':'value5','key3':'value6'},
             {'key1':'value7', 'key2':'value8','key3':'value9'}]

output = defaultdict(list)
for d in your_list:
    for key, value in d.items():
        output[key].append(value)
```

And the output would be

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'key1': ['value1', 'value4', 'value7'],
             'key2': ['value2', 'value5', 'value8'],
             'key3': ['value3', 'value6', 'value9']})
```

---

About lowercase variable names [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)